# opencart - customer table, cart field encoding

Tags: opencart

I have a need to show the abandoned cart to my visitors. I have looked around and found out that opencart saves the cart in serialized array in customer table under cart field.
My problem is that even though I unserialize the array I cant really tell what options the customer has chosen as it still somehow in unreadable to me. I am not sure if it requires some kind of decoding or not, thats probably what I may need.
Here is what I have
the cart field is `a:1:{s:31:"59:YToxOntpOjIzNztzOjI6IjQyIjt9";i:1;}`
but when I unserialize it, it shows an array like this

```
array(1) { ["59:YToxOntpOjIzNztzOjI6IjQyIjt9"]=> int(1) }
```

I know that 59 is the product_id, I have no idea what it (YToxOntpOjIzNztzOjI6IjQyIjt9) is after that? or how to even decode it?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use base64_decode on that string.
Here is a clue, from system/library/cart.php:

```
$options = unserialize(base64_decode($product[1]));
```